# Define and use class methods from variable

Tags: python

Let's say I have two `classes` with some methods.

First `class`:

```
@dataclass
class MyFirstClass:
    y1: List[float]
    y2: List[float]
    
    @property
    def my_func1(self) -> List[float]:
        return self.y1-self.y2

    @property
    def my_func2(self) -> List[float]:
        return self.y1+self.y2

    @property
    def my_func3(self) -> List[float]:
        return self.y1*self.y2
```

Second `class`:

```
@dataclass
class MySecondClass:
    list_vals: List[float]
    
    @property
    def norm1(self):
        return self.list_vals
 
    @property
    def norm2(self):
        return self.list_vals / numpy.mean(self.list_vals)
```

So my question is two fold.
Say in my `main` I have something like:

```
def main():
    FUNCTION = <?>
    NORM = <?>

    y1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    y2 = [3, 4, 5, 6, 7]

    test = MyFirstClass(y1, y2).my_func1
```

Then I just call `MyFirstClass` with the `y1` and `y2` lists and get an output.

But as can be seen in the beginning of `main` I have `FUNCTION` and `NORM`. Is there any way to call `MyFirstClass` from there, and then reuse it all through `main`, i.e. something like:

```
FUNCTION = MyFirstClass.my_func1

test = FUNCTION(y1, y2)
```

This doesn't work obviously. So how can one do that ?

Also, and this is probably a build upon the above, how can I, once again, choose the `norm` function to be used in the other `class` ? For instance, if I update `MyFirstClass` a bit to:

```
@dataclass
    class MyFirstClassUpdated:
        y1: List[float]
        y2: List[float]
        norm: NORM
        
        @property
        def my_func1(self) -> List[float]:
            return norm(self.y1)-norm(self.y2)
    
        @property
        def my_func2(self) -> List[float]:
            return norm(self.y1)+norm(self.y2)
    
        @property
        def my_func3(self) -> List[float]:
            return norm(self.y1)*norm(self.y2)
```

And then when the class is called it takes the `NORM` argument from the `main` function, i.e. something like:

```
FUNCTION = MyFirstClass.func1
NORM = MySecondClass.norm1

test = FUNCTION(y1, y2, NORM)
```

I have no idea if this is even possible without making the code "uglier".

Comment: Is the last example supposed to use `MyFirstClassUpdated`?

Comment: `y1` and `y2` are arguments to `MyFirstClass`, not `MyFirstClass.my_func1`. The closest to what you are looking for is to make `FUNCTION` a bound method: `FUNCTION = MyFirstClass(y1, y2).my_func1; FUNCTION()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create an instance of `MyFirstClass`, and pass it as the `self` argument to the function.

```
FUNCTION = MyFirstClass.my_func1
mfc = MyFirstClass(y1, y2)
test = FUNCTION(mfc)
```

Comment: That seemed to do the trick. But how would I go about providing the NORM function into that class as well ?

Comment: You need to do it similarly. You have to make an instance of `MySecondClass` to call the `NORM` function on.

Comment: Where is the `list_vals` argument to `MySecondClass` in the second example?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your last comment. In the second example the `list_vals` are just the `self.y1` and `self.y2`. `MySecondClass` is unchanged compared to `MyFirstClassUpdated`. I just want to use the `MySecondClass` and its methods in the `MyFirstClassUpdated` class. That was not used in the first `MyFirstClass`.

Comment: Why are you trying to do this with dataclasses? It seems like you just want ordinary functions that you can pass arguments to.